# Send a keyboard command into a program using cmd Windows7

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, cmd

I am writing my first .bat file ever.  I am trying to open a file and print it.  So far I have managed to open the file.  After that I want to sent in the keyboard command of Ctrl+P to print the screen.  I am using a brother label printer and from what there tech department told me, the only way to use the printer is from the software that came with the printer.  I have looked up how to send commands from CMD in Windows and have not found anything that is helpful.  What would I do to send int Ctrl+P from the .bat file/command line?

Here is the script.

```
@echo off

 title My First batch file
 echo Hello!
 start Ptedit50.exe "c:\My Labels\PraxisBadge.lbx"  
 start>Ctrl+P 
 pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I tested this with notepad and it worked well.

```
@echo off
setlocal

title My First batch file
echo Hello!
start Ptedit50.exe "c:\My Labels\PraxisBadge.lbx"  
call :SendCtrlP "Name in Windowtitle"
pause
exit /b

:SendCtrlP <app>
setlocal
set vbs=%Temp%\_.vbs
>%vbs% echo set s = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
>>%vbs% echo s.appactivate "%~1"
>>%vbs% echo s.sendkeys "^p"
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know where they is a good tutorial on Wscript.Shell?